# How to compare multiple columns of one file with one column of another and display matches from second file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, text

I have two files like this:

File 1

```
apple fruit 10 4
strawberry fruit 22 11
berry fruit 33 33
ball toy 1 12
straw thing 2 33
```

File 2

```
strawberry straw berry
rawberry raw berry
```

I want to compare column 1 of file 2 with column 1 of file 1, column 2 of file 2 with column 1 of file 1, column 3 of file 2 with column 1 of file 1. If match is found, I want to display all three matching lines from file 1.

Here, the output should be:

```
strawberry fruit 22 11
straw thing 2 33
berry fruit 33 33
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0} $1 in a && $2 in a && $3 in a{print a[$1] ORS a[$2] ORS a[$3]}' file1 file2
strawberry fruit 22 11
straw thing 2 33
berry fruit 33 33
```

- Save lines based on first column of `file1` and then print matching lines if all three columns of `file2` lines match